# Attempt to call field 'defaultName' (a string value) error

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm getting a strange **Attempt to call field 'defaultName' (a string value)** when i add ***" some more text "*** to my code below:

```
--
alert = native.showAlert( "saved!",  "Your score is saved to " ..defaultName " some more text " ..allScore_txt , { "Done" }, onComplete )
--
```

any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a `..` after `defaultName` and so Lua thinks you mean a function call, hence the error message. Lua allows function calls in the form `identifier"string"` as shorthand for identifier("string")`.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh I wasted one hour not noticing this and thinking increasingly improbable and more exotic ways to debug this... Thank you!